# How to write latitude and longitude on image in Swift 3.0?

Tags: swift3

I followed below code and it is not at all showing the image. what would be the wrong here? I was trying to debug newimage shows nil.

I was unable to resolve it.

```
func textOnImage(text: NSString, atPoint: CGPoint,capturedImage:UIImage?) -> UIImage? {

    if let capturedImage = capturedImage {

        // Setup the font specific variables
        let textColor = UIColor.white
        let textFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 14)!

        // Setup the image context using the passed image

        let scale = UIScreen.main.scale

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(capturedImage.size, false, scale)

        // Setup the font attributes that will be later used to dictate how the text should be drawn
        let textFontAttributes = [
            NSFontAttributeName: textFont,
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor,
            ] as [String : Any]

        // Create a point within the space that is as bit as the image

        let rect =  CGRect(x: atPoint.x, y: atPoint.y, width: capturedImage.size.width, height: capturedImage.size.height)

        // Draw the text into an image

        text.draw(in: rect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)

        // Create a new image out of the images we have created
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        // End the context now that we have the image we need
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
//Pass the image back up to the caller
        return newImage!
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: looks like image frame missing. please check

Comment: could you please mention where it could be.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include below line

```
capturedImage.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: capturedImage.size.width, height:capturedImage.size.height))
```

so your method looks like

```
 func textOnImage(text: NSString, atPoint: CGPoint,capturedImage:UIImage?) -> UIImage?{

        if let capturedImage = capturedImage{

            // Setup the font specific variables
            let textColor = UIColor.white
            let textFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 14)!

            // Setup the image context using the passed image


            let scale = UIScreen.main.scale

            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(capturedImage.size, false, scale)



            // Setup the font attributes that will be later used to dictate how the text should be drawn
            let textFontAttributes = [
                NSFontAttributeName: textFont,
                NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor,
                ] as [String : Any]



            capturedImage.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: capturedImage.size.width, height:capturedImage.size.height))



            // Create a point within the space that is as bit as the image


            let rect =  CGRect(x: atPoint.x, y: atPoint.y, width: capturedImage.size.width, height: capturedImage.size.height)

            // Draw the text into an image

            text.draw(in: rect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)



            // Create a new image out of the images we have created
            let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

            // End the context now that we have the image we need
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

            //Pass the image back up to the caller
            return newImage!

        }
        return nil

    }

}
```